# To find a DOM element using jQuery and replace its string

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very complex DOM structure,
A small for example or say demo of code,

```
<div>
<div class="test_data">
    <span>sample 1</span>
    <span>sample 1</span>
    <span>sample 3</span>
    <span>sample 1</span>
    <span>sample 2</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Now on above example, I have to find all the  tag having **sample 1** and want to replace it by another string say as **example**, I want to do this stuff using jQuery.

Comment: It's good practice to accept someone's answer if they've helped you out. This is how StackOverflow works. Check out the faq (http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and accept either mine or Reigel's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.test_data span:contains(sample 1)').html('sample');
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z57xv/)

but I think you want more than this. Well maybe this will help someone.

```
$('.test_data span:contains(sample 1)').html(function(i,html){
     return html.replace('sample 1','sample');
});
```

this will replace the particular text.

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z57xv/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("span:contains('sample 1')").text("example");
```

Or if you need all spans in a specific div, add it before the `span:`

```
$("#somedivId span:contains('sample 1')").text("example");
```

**easy peasy :)**

Comment: $("span:contains('sample 1')").text("example");